# Using data.tables, trying to aggregate data by column index

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I'm having some trouble using the data.table package. I'm using this package because it seems to be very fast and efficient with memory and it will be working on a very large data set (~ 6m x 300).

So, basically an example of the problem I'm having is:

```
AA <- matrix(runif(50,0,100), 10,5)
AA <- data.table(AA)
colnames(AA) <- c("one","two","three","four","five")
AA[,"key"] <- c(1:10)
setkey(AA,key)

BB <- matrix(c("A1","A1","B1","A1","C1","F1","T1","Y1","S1","S1","B2","C2","V2","G2","R2","U2","P2","Q2","A2","R2"),10,2)
BB <- data.table(BB)
BB[,"key"] <- c(1:10)
setkey(BB,key)

CC <- AA[BB]
```

This gives the following

```
> CC
  key       one       two     three     four     five V1 V2
 [1,]   1 70.528360  7.901987 66.827238 44.51487 26.22273 A1 B2
 [2,]   2 38.560889 31.808611  7.877950 34.51093 51.27989 A1 C2
 [3,]   3 70.164154 16.636281 59.127573 79.95673 19.07643 B1 V2
 [4,]   4 82.019267 86.958215  3.335632 44.19048 46.29047 A1 G2
 [5,]   5 24.980403 25.352212 78.240760 93.69818 46.64401 C1 R2
 [6,]   6  1.062644 30.214449 15.920193 35.15496 97.86995 F1 U2
 [7,]   7  5.242374 47.591899 56.879902 70.05319 82.48689 T1 P2
 [8,]   8 69.646271 69.576102 38.766948 38.62866 74.69404 Y1 Q2
 [9,]   9 25.335255 54.638416  5.777238 80.87692 34.11951 S1 A2
[10,]  10 54.844424 18.645826 59.370042 48.24352 84.02630 S1 R2
```

What I'm trying to do is aggregate the data by V1 and V2

```
> CC[,length(one), by=V1]
     V1 V1.1
[1,] A1    3
[2,] B1    1
[3,] C1    1
[4,] F1    1
[5,] T1    1
[6,] Y1    1
[7,] S1    2

> CC[,length(one), by=V2]
  V2 V1
[1,] B2  1
[2,] C2  1
[3,] V2  1
[4,] G2  1
[5,] R2  2
[6,] U2  1
[7,] P2  1
[8,] Q2  1
[9,] A2  1
```

The problem I'm having is that if I don't know explicitly the names of the columns I want to aggregate by, or if I want to loop through say 100 columns getting 100 different aggregates, how can I do this?

The data.table reference manual says this works the way it does since the variables are referenced in the scope of the data table, so CC[, V1] will give the one column, whereas CC[, "V1"] won't. It says you can use something like

```
x <- quote(V1)
CC[,length(one), by=eval(x)]
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I've tried a few things such as setting up the variable names in a vector and various combinations of quote(), noquote(), enquote() but I can't seem to figure out if it's possible.

How can I set this up to loop through a list of column names aggregating by each as it goes?

If not, are there any better ways to aggregate a large data set like this quickly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are going for -- I think you may have to come up with a better example of what you are trying to do.

You can, for instance, pass in a character vector in `by`, so this would work:

```
agg.by <- "V1"
CC[, length(one), by=agg.by]
```

If you want to summarize over "unknown" columns in your subsets, you can `lapply` over the `.SD` data.table that is in scope inside each of your aggregates, eg:

```
CC[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=agg.by]
```

If you are only summarizing a few columns from your original data.table, use the `.SDcols` argument, eg:

```
CC[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=agg.by, .SDcols=c('one', 'two')]
```

I think some combination of the above is going to address the question you are asking, but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're after.

If you can give a better chunk of example data and expected results, I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear but it turns out this 'agg.by <- "V1"; CC[, length(one), by=agg.by]' actually works. Not sure what I was doing wrong before!? I am basically trying to produce graphs on all the categorical variables in a dataset. But I don't know what they'll be called or where they'll be located, so I wanted to loop through the dataset making graphs. The trouble was it didn't seem to be working setting a column name as a variable (like you did with 'agg.by <- "V1"'). I think this might be because I was trying something like defining a variable as 'c("V1", "V2, ...)'. Thanks!